# Capturing email reply messages in Python

Tags: python, api, email

I have a web application in Python that allows someone to post a message. When this occurs, my application will automatically dispatch an email to the other user, who is following the "conversation/post". The user receive the email and replies with a message such as "Ok".

I want capture this reply message to a post in my application. I see this in applications such as Assana. How I can do this? Does there exists a service or API I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Any email sent from the user will go to the domain mail server. If you want to receive it in a POST request, you'll have to write a separate application that retrieves email messages from the mail server and then sends the ones you want in a HTTP request to your web server. You'll then have to run your application as a daemon/service, and have it periodically poll the server for new messages (or use [IMAP IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE))

You may want to use [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) to retrieve the emails.

Developing a complete two-way bridge between a web page and email with conversation tracking will likely require knowledge about [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) and [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_delivery_agent) administration